# No key field(s) specified in attribute mapping. inDataDirector import bundle for Pimcore

Tags: pimcore, datadirector

The DataDirector import claims '[WARNING] No key field(s) specified in attribute mapping. Falling back to using all mapped fields as key fields. Please go to attribute mapping and set one or more fields as key fields which can be used to find already existing elements.'
All Pimcore Fields are already mapped.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

- find the field which can be used as a key on 'Attribute mapping' /
  'Attributzuordnung' (2) tab in dataDirector for your dataport.
- Click on '<>' icon to open callback function editor
- Activate the checkbox on top of callback function editor
- Optionally, you can set this field as unique and mandatory in the class definition